# Agregar header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" en HttpHeaders junto a otros js angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, http

estoy realizando una peticion http desde js y de la forma que la necesito deo agregar varios headers, pero me manda error como lo estoy haciendo.

```
getAllDatos(pUrl: string, usr: string, pass: string): Observable<any> {
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + usr + ':' + pass)
.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:' '*')
    };
    return this.httpClient.get(pUrl + '/QRY/GET_ALL_DATAS&Content-Type=text/json', options);
  }
```

He buscado varias opciones, funciona bien pero al agregar:  `.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:' '*')`   me manda el error

```
TS1005: ',' expected.
```

alguien tiene alguna que funcione correctamente

Comment: "me manda el error". Cuál?

Comment: Son problemas de `CORS` esa parte deben ser habilitados desde el backend.

Comment: `TS1005: ',' expected.` Ahí te dice que le falta una coma.

Comment: si, agregue la coma, pero me manda error de sintaxis
En si es la sintaxis de agregar los 2 headers

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaron en los comentarios falta la `,` del segundo `set`

```
.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```